# Arrays.copyof is connecting the two Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

I am writing some code to set all the values in the rows and columns of a matrix to zero if any row or column in the matrix has a zero.

In my code, I have copied the elements into another array called `copy[][]` and modified the elements in `copy[][]`, thus keeping the actual array `array[][]` unmodified.

However, I can see that even `array[][]` is getting modified.  I can see the value of elements in `array[][]` changing during debug mode, but I have been unable to figure out how this is happening.

Can someone please help?

For reference, here is the code I am working on:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MatrixZero {

static int copy[][];

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println("Enter the number of rows and columns: ");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int m = scanner.nextInt();
    int n = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the elements of the matrix:");
    int array[][] = new int[m][n];
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            array[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
    }
    //copy the array to another array
    copy = Arrays.copyOf(array,array.length);
    System.out.println("The array copied is: ");
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            System.out.print(copy[i][j]+"  ");
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
    //Code to make the entire row and column of a matrix zero if
    //any one element is zero
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            if(array[i][j]==0){
                //call a method to make the entire row and column zero
                makeZero(i, j,n);
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("The final matrix: ");
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            System.out.print(copy[i][j]+"  ");
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
    scanner.close();

}

public static void makeZero(int row,int column,int n){



    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        copy[row][i] = 0;
        //copy[i][column] = 0;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        copy[i][column] = 0;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: have you tried with this `if(copy[i][j]==0){
                makeZero(i, j,n);
            }`

Comment: I got the solution. Thank you all :) The issue is that when you use Arrays.copyOf or use clone on an multi dimensional array the new variable created will only be a shallow copy. That means that it will be still be pointing to the same reference in the memory. So if the copy is changed so will the initial variable. The only way to do this it to iterate over the list and copy the values manually.